# electronic specific heat as a function of temperature AND fermi-level?

Tags: solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

[image: Specific heat as a function of electron-temperature and Fermi-level for GaAs]
I don't really understand the above plot. 
I know that the specific heat depends on temperature..that is clear. But why are there multiple curves for different Fermi-Levels? I always thought that the Fermi-Level (or at least the quasi-fermi-level) is constant for a given temperature. Why are there multiple Fermi-Levels for the same temperature and how can I find the "total" specific heat?

I'm thankful for any hints/links

Comment: A bit more of the context this plot came from would be helpful. Generally the Fermi level can depend on a number of different parameters (for example the level of doping) which allow it to be varied at a fixed temperature.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a result I found in some textbook on first principle calculations a long time ago. In this case the composition of the material is constant. Maybe those curves correspond to different bands? Is that possible?

Comment: For first principles calculations the Fermi level is just a parameter in the simulation. You can just add or remove electrons as you like to place it wherever you want.